# Why does it return the wrong String?

Tags: java, string, if-statement

I'm new to Java, so apologies beforehand.

I'm making a method that takes the exam mark of a student (int mark) and  returns a grade (String grade). But it sometimes returns the wrong grade.

```
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
        String grade = "";
        if (mark < 40) {
            return ("Fail"); 
            }
        else if (mark < 50) {
            return ("3rd");
            }
        else if (mark < 60) {
            return ("2ii");
            }
        else if (mark < 70) {
            return ("2i");
            }
        else if (mark >= 70) {
            return ("1st"); 
            }
        else if (mark < 0) {
            return ("Invalid mark");
            }
        else if (mark > 100) {
            return ("Invalid mark"); 
            }
        return grade;
        }
```

```
System.out.println(labExample.calculateGrade(50));
```

The problem is that whenever i put in a value -1 it returns as "Fail" instead of "Invalid code." The same goes for over 100 as it returns as "1st" instead of "Invalid code."

Even though I've stated what to return if the grade is <0 or >100 it seems to ignore it.

Any help or pointers would be great. Thanks.

Comment: *"The problem is that whenever i put in a value -1 it returns as "Fail" instead of "Invalid code.""* -1 is < 40, so your first `if`'s condition is true.

Comment: Try to put the `< 0` check as first condition... And think about the ones that check ranges between 70 and 100, you won't get an `"invalid mark"` there because 200 is >= 70.

Comment: `if` condition executes the first successful resolved condition and then skips the rest of the `else if` conditions. If no condition is met, then only, control goes to `else` block (if present.). Please understand how `if` block works: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: Ah, so it was a simple case of getting them in the correct order. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that whenever i put in a value -1 it returns as "Fail" instead of "Invalid code.""*

`-1` is `< 40`, so your first `if`'s condition is true. That means your `return ("Invalid mark");` code runs, which terminates the method — none of the rest of the code is executed. `return` doesn't just set a return value but continue with subsequent statements, it *ends* the method call.

Also note that you have a logical error later, you have a series of `else if` statements leading up to `else if (mark < 70)` followed by `if (mark >= 70)`. That `>= 70` will **always** be true. If `mark` were `< 70`, the previous `if` condition would have been true and you would never have got there.

The correct way to do this is to check **in order**, probably (in this case) from lowest to highest, but perhaps with the "Invalid mark" check up front.

Other notes:

- You don't need `()` around return values, `return` isn't a function/method.
- You don't need `else` if you're doing `return` in the `if` bodies.
- You never used `grade` so there's no reason to have it in the code

So:

```
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
    if (mark < 0 || mark > 100) {
        return "Invalid mark";
    }
    if (mark < 40) {
        return "Fail"; 
    }
    if (mark < 50) {
        return "3rd";
    }
    if (mark < 60) {
        return "2ii";
    }
    if (mark < 70) {
        return "2i";
    }
    return "1st"; 
}
```

Or assigning to `grade` and returning it at the end instead, which some consider best practice (and others consider unnecessary complication):

```
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
    String grade; // ** Note I don't do = ""; I want the compiler to warn me if I try to use it without assigning to it

    if (mark < 0 || mark > 100) {
        grade = "Invalid mark";
    }
    else if (mark < 40) {
        grade = "Fail"; 
    }
    else if (mark < 50) {
        grade = "3rd";
    }
    else if (mark < 60) {
        grade = "2ii";
    }
    else if (mark < 70) {
        grade = "2i";
    }
    else {
        grade = "1st"; 
    }
    return grade;
}
```

Note I needed the `else`s there, because I'm not `return`ing in the `if` bodies.

Comment: Great answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your logic order is wrong. Correct logic is

```
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
    String grade = "";
     if (mark < 0) {
        return ("Invalid mark");
        }
    else if (mark > 100) {
        return ("Invalid mark"); 
        }
    else if (mark < 40) {
        return ("Fail"); 
        }
    else if (mark < 50) {
        return ("3rd");
        }
    else if (mark < 60) {
        return ("2ii");
        }
    else if (mark < 70) {
        return ("2i");
        }
    else if (mark >= 70) {
        return ("1st"); 
        }
    return grade;
    }
```

Comment: You don't really need the elses. The fact the return statement is passed, means you can only have code for the else situation after the if blocks

Answer (score 0):

-1 < 100 is true: so it returns "Fail"

101 >= 70 is true: so it returns "1st"

if doing it with IfEse: Check your borders first! Then do the grades.

Comment: Actually, it returns "Fail" because -1 < 40

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort also the order of the various IF. 
In other words it matches the first valid IF.

Another possible option, to avoid sorting the IFs, could be to check if like

```
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
        if (mark >= 0 && mark < 40) {
            return "Fail"; 
         }
        else if (mark >= 40 && mark < 50) {
            return ("3rd");
            }
        else if (mark >= 50 && mark < 60) {
            return ("2ii");
            }
        else if (mark >= 60 && mark < 70) {
            return ("2i");
            }
        else if (mark >= 70 && mark < 100) {
            return ("1st"); 
            }            
         return ("Invalid mark");
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably the way you think of this problem.

You should first think about all the areas you need and than put them in the condition range.

```java
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
        String grade = "";
if(mark < 0 || mark > 100){
            grade = "fail";
        } else {
            if (mark < 40) {
                grade = ("Fail"); 
            }else if (mark < 50) {
                grade = ("3rd");

            }else if (mark < 60) {
                grade = ("2ii");

            }else if (mark < 70) {
                grade = ("2i");

            }else if = (mark >= 70) {
                grade ("1st"); 
            }
        }
        return grade;
```

Answer (score -1):

Always check else if in ascending order.

```
public String calculateGrade(int mark) {
        String grade = "";
        if (mark < 0) {
            return ("Invalid mark");
            }
        else if (mark < 40) {
            return ("Fail"); 
            }
        else if (mark < 50) {
            return ("3rd");
            }
        else if (mark < 60) {
            return ("2ii");
            }
        else if (mark < 70) {
            return ("2i");
            }
        else if (mark >= 70) {
            return ("1st"); 
            }
        else if (mark > 100) {
            return ("Invalid mark"); 
            }
        return grade;
    }
```

Now it should work as expected.